# Is there a faster way I can calculate binary operation in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, binary

Suppose I have a binary string: `z = abc`, where a,b,c are either 0 or 1, so we can convert `c` into an integer from 0 to 7. Now I want to give a,b,c another 'layer' of value, where a = 1/2^1 = 1/2, b = 1/2^2 = 1/4, c = 1/2^3 = 1/8. My goal is to create a dictionary, where the keys are integers 0-7, and values are the associated calculations based on a,b,c values.

The only way I'm able to solve this question is to 'brute force' the results. For example, when the key is 5 (z = 101), the value would be 1/2+0+1/8 = 5/8, and perform all calculations manually, then append the item to the dictionary. Is there a tool / method in python that will allow me to create the calculation faster? I really have no idea how I can do that. Any suggestions / help is appreciated.

Comment: What are your actual inputs? For three-digit binary, the operation should be neither costly nor frequent enough to need optimization.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if the key is `5`, and you want a corresponding value of `5/8` or `0.625`, then just divide the key by eight. Dividing a binary number by two has the effect of "shifting" all the digits over to the right, just like how dividing a number by ten in base-10 has the effect of shifting all the digits over to the right. So, dividing by eight in base-2 will move the digits over three places.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the comment! The input I want is the length of `z`, I want to generalize the operation into larger `z` string.

Comment: @IGY what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on my comment a bit:

```
for key, value in {bin(key)[2:]: key/8 for key in range(8)}.items():
    print(f"{key:>3}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
  0: 0.0
  1: 0.125
 10: 0.25
 11: 0.375
100: 0.5
101: 0.625
110: 0.75
111: 0.875
>>>
```

Is this the output you're looking for?

Comment: Elaborating on your comment as well: The result seems to always be `int(z, 2) / 2**len(z)` (assuming here that `z` is a bit-string). Because the OP simply divides the value of all bits by `2**len(z)` the result should be the same, as you observed in the comment

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there a way to convert the keys to be integers?

Comment: @IGY Sure, just do `key: key/8`, rather than `bin(key)[2:]: key/8`. `key` is already an integer.

Answer (score 2):

One naïve approach would be to iterate over the bit-string, and multiply each bit by the matching power of 0.5:

```py
res = 0
for i, bit in enumerate(z, 1):
    res += int(bit) * 0.5**i
```

For `z = "101"` this will give `res` as 0.625 which is `5/8`

---

Could be compacted using `sum`:

```
res = sum(int(bit) * 0.5**i for i, bit in enumerate(z, 1))
```

---

If `z` is actually an integer, just change the `z`s above to `format(z, 'b')` to get its binary string representation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to benefit vectorization :

```
import numpy as np
num =[1,0,1] 
d = np.array(num)
r = 1 / np.logspace(1, len(num), num=len(num), base=2)
np.matmul(r,d)
```

output :

```
> 0.625
```